# Mail domains without mandatory phone numbers

Tags: manual-testing

I'm looking for some mail domains where I could create accounts without mandatory phone numbers required ?

Comment: Can you add more context for this question. What are you trying to do? I'm assuming you don't need a mail domain but rather an email service like GMail or Hotmail? Would https://mailosaur.com/ help?

Answer (score 1):

I generally use Mailinator for testing purposes, but when this fails my go to one is Yopmail.